# how to set attribute value in angular

Tags: angular

In jquery selector iam using this code to set attribute value.
$('.modelimage').attr('src',imagesource)

In same way in Angular how to set attribute value for div element whose class is modelimage

Answer (score 0):

On your html page

```
<div class="modelimage" [yourAttribute]="value"></div>
```

On your ts component

```
value: string = ''
```

With this, when you will modify your `value`, it will change the attribute value.

Comment: <div class="zoomimage"><img src="" class="modelimage" alt="Chania" style="cursor:pointer"></div>                                                                                                                 This is my html tag ,i want to set src attribute dynamically .how to do it

Comment: Do it like I said, `<div class="zoomimage"><img [src]="sourcePath" class="modelimage" alt="Chania" style="cursor:pointer"></div>`. As you can see, the attribute src is under bracket, this mean that the element `sourcePath` is 'linked' to him. So every time you change the value of this element on your component, it will be changed too on your attribute.

Comment: $scope.showLargeImage = function (text) {  var imagesource=  $('#'text).attr("src")  $('.modelimage').attr('src',imagesource)  if(window.innerWidth>768)
        $('.modelimage').css({ width: window.innerWidth - 400 + 'px', height: window.innerHeight -150+ 'px' });
        else
        $('.modelimage').css({ width: window.innerWidth - 55 + 'px', height: window.innerHeight -250+ 'px' })
       $("#ZoomModal").modal('show');
   };

Comment: this is my html tag from where click event fires                                                                                        <td class="imgcolumn"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQNcSAg7f3C33-Tgrjpd9oSH9rif235zop3Kg&usqp=CAU" (click)="showLargeImage('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQNcSAg7f3C33-Tgrjpd9oSH9rif235zop3Kg&usqp=CAU')" id="img1" alt="Chania" style="cursor:pointer" width="50" height="50"></td>                                so how to change angular js function to angular function.

Comment: so how to change angular js function which suits to angular

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the original question. If you have trouble with translating from AngularJS to Angular, I think you should learn a little bit more both of the languages. Or post another question on StackOverflow.

Comment: really you need use `attr` before the name of attribute `[attr.name_of_attribute]="'variable'"`, e.g. `[attr.alt]="myvariable'"`

Comment: In his case, he uses a DOM property so there is no need to add attr before the attibute.